# Form input type option problem

Tags: cakephp

```
echo $this->Form->input('country', array('type' => 'select', 'options' => $country_list));
```

This generates a select box with all the countries. But I'd like the default to be empty. I looked into the manual and setting `'selected' => ''` does not work either.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `'empty' => ''` in the `options` array. You can also set it to any other value you'd like.

Comment: my array structure was incorrect, and this made me realize that. Thanks